# Nexus 7 Possibly Bricked

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I have a 1st gen Nexus 7 (32GB). I used the steps [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation) to successfully install Ubuntu 13.04 desktop onto the tablet. It was working fine and then I decided to upgrade to Ubuntu Touch. I booted the tablet into fast boot mode but the commands `adb devices` and `sudo fastboot devices` would not see the device. I am performing these steps from an Ubuntu 12.04 desktop PC. Prior to installing 13.04 the device was seen fine. I made the mistake of performing the 'Device factory reset' step [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) - Step 2. Now when I try to boot the device I get the following:

```
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: no such file or directory
mount: mounting /dev on /root/sys failed: no such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: no such file or directory
Targe filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.

BusyBox v1.20.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.20.0-0ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter help for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I have searched the web but every reference to this problem is from people who still have ADB access to the device so they can recover by flashing the tablet again. I can attach a keyboard to the USB port and access the BusyBox console but I don't know what steps to do to recover from my error. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks

**UPDATE:**

No combination of power and volume buttons could get into **fastboot** mode. However , once the tablet lost all power (since I could not shut it down from busybox) and I recharged it, the tablet came up in the **fastboot** mode. Based on the one suggestion provided, I was able to connect using 'sudo fastboot devices' instead of 'adb devices'. I want to thanks both people that responded for their help. I would up vote the answer but being new to the forum I do not have enough reputation yet to do so. But thanks for the help.

Comment: No, it is just the stock recovery

Comment: Had I flashed TWRP would that have made recovery possible? I only ask for future reference.

Comment: In looking back at the steps that I ran I did execute the following: 
   fastboot flash recovery saucy-preinstalled-recovery-armel+grouper.img

Comment: I was following the steps from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install - Manual download & installation. But in short I guess I did.

Answer (score 0):

I had roughly the same problem (back in May/Jun), when I tried to install **Ubuntu Touch** 13.04 (beta) over a previous install of 13.04 'Core' (AKA 'Desktop') on a **Nexus 7** (16GB).

The first attempt (using **phablet-tools**) failed to complete, and I could not get any useful status from **adb**.

---

I recovered by getting the tablet into **fastboot** visible mode, then re-flashing to stock Android. I don't remember exact steps, but its probably pasted into one of my **Nexus 7** posts from that time period.

***Will research further ..***

---

### UPDATE:

(adapted from [Problem restoring android after trying Ubuntu on Nexus 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278400/problem-restoring-android-after-trying-ubuntu-on-nexus-7))

The various builds/firmwares for the **Nexus 7** all require different modes to recover and/or re-flash.

Try **different** power-up states, to try to get to: 'fastboot' mode, 'recovery mode', and 'Ubuntu running'.

Each time wait, *until the device is that mode*, before inserting the USB cable.

You will see different results for:

```
sudo fastboot devices
adb devices
lsusb
```

*With the device usually only responding to one variant at a time ..*

***Report on what (if any) status you can get ..***

Comment: In my case I cannot even see the device using **adb** so I don't know of any way to flash back to Android or Ubuntu. The tablet only boots into the BusyBox shell, not into normal **fastboot** (i.e., with the Android character), even when pressing power and the volume simultaneously.